# is the iPhone alarm supposed to be silent in Silent mode?

Tags: iphone, alarm

I have a problem where my iPhone alarm sometimes doesn't go off, causing me to oversleep. I thought I was just sleeping through it, but I tested creating new alarms for (current time + 1 minute) and the first time I did this, it didn't go off.

My iPhone was locked and charging. I unlocked my iPhone and saw the alarm like a notification at the top of the screen. The next 3 times I created an alarm this didn't happen and I can't replicate it.

I contacted Apple Support and the support person said that the alarm is silent when the switch at the top left of my iPhone 6s is switched to silent. However I think they are wrong because I tested and the alarm still goes off (with sound) when it is switched to silent. So is the support person misinformed or am I going crazy?

Comment: misinformed. I keep my iPhone in silent mode all the time and still use the alarm to wake me up. Be sure you don't lower the alarm volume accidentally, though